# Write a Java program to help a convenience store clerk decide whether or not to sell beer to a customer?

Tags: java

I need to write a program that helps a convenience store clerk decide whether or not to sell beer to a customer. Beer can only be sold to somebody who is 21 years old or more, and has enough money (beer costs $5.00). If the customer is too young, tell them how many years they must wait before returning. If they have too little money, tell them how much more is needed. I don't know what to do, please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class example1 {

  public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

      int age;
      double beerPrice;
      double cash;

      System.out.print( "Please type customer age:" );
      age = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print ("Type customer cash amount:");
      cash= scan.nextDouble();
      System.out.println();

      if (age <= 21) {
        System.out.println(21-age);
      }
   }
}
```

This is all I have so far. Each time I run the program, if the age is 21 or greater, it still prints age when I don't want it to. Please help me complete this program. Not asking for a hand out.

Comment: Works for me - doesn't print out age when I enter 22. Are you sure you are running the version shown?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Sometimes the compiler gets confused and doesn't register new changes when it should. Try saving the file you're working on, then compiling, then try restarting the compiler. If that fails, there is usually a 'clean project' function in many compilers that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
public class example1{
public static void main (String [] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

int age;
double beerPrice;
double cash;


System.out.print( "Please type customer age:" );
age = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println();

System.out.print ("Type customer cash amount:");
cash= scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println();

if (age < 21) {
  System.out.println(""+(21-age)+" years till you can buy beer");
}
if(cash<5.0)
{
  System.out.println("$"+(5.0-cash)+" more is required");
}
}
}
```